# Dudas sobre limpieza de datos con expresiones regulares PHP

Tags: php, regex, csv

Tengo un CSV que tiene eans (ID). Los eans, por definición, deberían tener 13 dígitos. Sin embargo, hay una gran cantidad de eans que no se ajustan al formato: con letras, con espacios, con "," de decimales etc. Resumen, tengo que limpiarlo. Por ahora tengo el siguiente código:

```
$archivo=fopen("articulos_erp.csv", "r"); //abro el archivo   

while(!feof($archivo)){ //Voy leyendo el CSV

    $linea=utf8_encode(fgets($archivo)); //Leo datos con CSV y lo voy poniendo en formato UTF8
    $arrayLineas=explode(";", $linea); //Aquí tengo mi array con los datos del CSV

    if(!empty($arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito cuando el ean esté vacío
        if(!preg_match("/[A-Za-z]/", $arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito los ean que tengan alguna letra
                if(!preg_match("/,/", $arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito las comas
                    var_dump($arrayLineas[0]);
                    $arrayLineasLimpio=trim(str_replace("", 0, $arrayLineas[0]))
                    //Si no vienen con 13 caracteres, meter 0 a la izq.
                    //quitar espacios
                }
        }
      }        
    }
```

El caso es que ahora tengo que: quitar los espacios que haya por delante y por detrás (que para eso uso trim) y lo más importante, que es lo que no me sale: cuando los caracteres tengan un mínimo de 7 caracteres, meter a la izquierda 6 ceros para que tenga 13 dígitos y tener un ean válido. Si tiene 8, 9, 10 etc. meter el número de 0 correspondiente para que tenga 13 dígitos. Entiendo que eso debería meterlo, como estoy haciendo, en $arrayLineasLimpio (en otro array), pero la verdad es que no sé cómo implementar el código para ello. Es decir, le he puesto el string replace, pero claro, eso me va a cambiar cualquier espacio por 0, que no tiene por qué estar necesariamente a la izquierda (puede estar en medio) y yo lo que quiero es coger ese espacio y meter el 0 a la izquierda. Pongo algunos ejemplos del resultado de salida que necesito:

```
EAN de entrada: 98765 8762345
EAN de salida: 0987658762345

EAN de entrada: 1 2 3 4 5 674
EAN de salida: 0000012345674
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? He estado dándole bastantes vueltas pero no se me ha ocurrido ninguna idea. Muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido hacerlo al final con este código:

```
                    $arrayLineasLimpio=str_replace(" ", "", $arrayLineasSinEspacios);
                    $numeroCaracteres=strlen($arrayLineasLimpio);
                    

                    switch($numeroCaracteres){

                        case 12:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="0".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="00".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="000".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break; 
                        case 9:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="0000".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="00000".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break; 
                        case 7:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="000000".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break;       
                    }
```

Básicamente con str_replace sustituyo espacios por nada ("") y luego le concateno según el caso 0 a la izquierda.

Comment: Creo que en este caso podrías usar `sprintf`. Revisa en el manual el ejemplo #6 `Especificador de posición con otros especificadores`. Con eso puedes rellenar a la izquierda del número, y conseguir una cadena de 13 caracteres.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)